# How to set up .gitignore file?

Tags: magento2, git

What is the best approach to set up a `.gitignore` file to ignore everything except:

```
/app/
composer.lock
```

Something like this:

```
# IGNORE
*
# DONT IGNORE
!/app
!composer.lock
```

I only want to version control the `app` directory where theme and custom modules are located, and the `composer.lock` file to version control the vendor files.

Comment: Could you explain why this .gitignore does not meet your requirements? https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/.gitignore i.e. why do want to ignore everything except /app/ and composer.lock

Comment: Tired using it and it didn't work as expected, so I am trying to debug why... therefore, I want to know how to ignore, not ignore each file

Comment: Hmm okay. Cause the .gitignore provided on Github allows you to pull your installation from your repository and after running `composer install` you can use the installation on your local machine or every other machine you want to pull your Magento 2 installation to. But wondering what answer you will get! :)

Comment: Git ignore only allows negating rules (not ignore) one level deeper as the inclusion (ignore) rules. So this can become complex...

Comment: I see... So this can't be achieved using one file only?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Files to ignore

/app/etc/env.php

#Files not to ignore

!/pub/media/.htaccess

#Folder to ignore

/pub/media/import/*
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#Ignore everything
*

#Files not to ignore
!/app
!composer.lock

#If there are subdirectories
!*/
```

Comment: what is that doing: `!*/`

Comment: Please do not just paste code into the answer form, but also explain what it is doing and how it will solve the OP's problem